# Terraform nested for expression

Tags: terraform

I have a module variable that is defined like this:

```
apis = {
  "${data.aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api1.id}" = ["blue", "green"],
  "${data.aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api2.id}" = ["blue"],
}
```

I need to convert this structure to the following:

```
[
    [data.aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api1.id, "blue"],
    [data.aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api1.id, "green"],
    [data.aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api2.id, "blue"],
]
```

for use in the `for_each` expression of a dynamic block for creating an api gateway usage plan

I have the following, which I think is so close to being correct, but the `id` variable in the first for expression is inaccessible within the body of the second for expression:

```
dynamic "api_stages" {
  for_each = flatten([
    for id, stages in var.apis: [
      for stage in stages: [id, stage]
    ]
  ])

  content {
    api_id = api_stages.value[0]
    stage  = api_stages.value[1]
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: If `id` isn't usable inside the nested `for` then that's a bug! I remember that something like this was fixed along the way during the 0.12 prereleases, so if you're not on the rc1 release might be worth trying upgrading first, but if you still see it not working on latest, please open a GitHub issue about it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much huffing and puffing, I decided to simplify my problem by defining my `apis` in the format that I was trying to convert the map to. This means I can iterate over the `apis` variable in the `for_each` without needing to transform it at all.

Not a solution to the exact problem, but a workaround